# morphism between projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ the plane cubic defined in homogeneus coordinate by $zy^2=x(x^2-z^2)$. I've proved that there is a morphism of $C$ on $C$ given by the following construction
Look first at $C \cap \mathbb{P}_2(K)_z$ with affine coordinate $X=x/z, Y=y/z$.
For all lines $l$ through the origin we want to interchange two point in $l \cap C$ (other than the origin). I've found that this is the map given by $(a,b)\to (-1/a,-b/a^2)$. How can I interpret this automorphism in terms of morphism between $\operatorname{Proj}(\mathbb{C}[x,y,z])$?

Comment: Wait, what does Proj(ℂ[x,y,z,w]) have to do with anything?

Comment: I was wrong... I wanted to say $Proj \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.

Comment: My question rises up by the fact I'd like to find a non banal example of morphism between schemes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **birational** automorphism $$F:\mathbb P^2_\mathbb C \stackrel {\cong}{\dashrightarrow} \mathbb P^2_\mathbb C: (x:y:z)\mapsto (-xz:-yz:x^2)$$ with inverse $F^{-1}=F$ 
 induces your  **regular** automorphism $f:C\stackrel {\cong}{\to}C$ with inverse $f^{-1}=f$.

Notice the slightly paradoxical fact that $(0:1:0)$ and $(0:0:1)$ are indeterminacy points for $F$ but are points where $f$ is regular, namely $f(0:1:0)=(0:0:1)$ and $f(0:0:1)=(0:1:0)$.
In other words, $f$ exchanges these points.